# Why the "<%= @comments.each { |comment| comment.title } %>" produces not a comment titles but "comment.inspect"...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Why the following code produces different output for me?

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.title %>
<% end %>
```

produces:

```
Title 1 title 2
```

but

```
<%= @comments.each { |comment| comment.title } %>
```

produces :

```
[#<Comment id: 1, commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: "Entry", title: "Title 1", body: "bla", subject: "", user_id: 1, parent_id: nil, lft: 1, rgt: 2, created_at: "2012-07-31 06:15:26", updated_at: "2012-07-31 06:15:26">, #<Comment id: 2, commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: "Entry", title: "tile 2", body: "one more comment", subject: "", user_id: 1, parent_id: nil, lft: 3, rgt: 4, created_at: "2012-08-01 06:58:57", updated_at: "2012-08-01 06:58:57">]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `<%= %>` will print out the value returned by the block of code.  In this case you have an enumerable `@comments` that you are calling each on.  The method `each` will return the enumerable that is used, in this case `@comments`.

If you wanted to print out the collection of titles, you could use:

```
<%= @comments.map{ |comment| comment.title } %>
```

or more succinctly

```
<%= @comments.map(&:title) %>
```

Comment: Where can I find documentation on `&` in this context?

Comment: Big thanks for explanation! Actually I want not title from comment:) I used this only for example to make the latter easier...
Actually I need in block: { |comment| render_comment_thread(comment) }.
The "render" helper goes threw threaded comments recursively and generate an html representation for them, and returns the latter...